# How to make only "/var/www/html/login" public on my apache2.4 server?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I need some help please.

I'm using `apache2.4` on my server. I'm blocking all requests to `/` using the following code:

```
    <Location />
    Deny from all
        AuthUserFile /path/.pass
        AuthName "Login"
        AuthType Basic
        Satisfy Any
        require valid-user
    </Location>
```

I'm using that because I have a service running (through proxyPass). With the following block, I'm serving an `index.html` that doesn't go though the proxy:

```
  <Location /login>
       # needs to come before the ProxyPass directives
       ProxyPass !
       Require all granted
    </Location>
```

On `/var/www/html/login` I have a `.htaccess` file containing:

```
Require All granted
```

Even with this config when I go to `example.com/login` it asks me to authenticate. What I'm missing here?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not mix "old" and "new" access directives. The problem here is that you used `Deny from all` on `/`, but `Require all granted` on `/login`. Since old access directives take precedence over the new ones, the one specified in the `/login` location does nothing.

Use `Require all denied` instead of `Deny from all`, and it should work.

Comment: True, but many servers have underlying directory configs that emit *order* and *deny from* type of directives when the compat access module is enabled and this may still not work if you cannot disable the compat module for other apps. In that case you would have to include both `Require all granted` and `order deny,allow` in the Login location block. Better insert `order deny,allow` in the root Location and remove both the `Satisfy Any` and `Deny from all` from the root Location block and only use `Require all granted` in the Location Login block.

Comment: Also the blocks for Location must be in the order shown in the configs. The login block later in the config than the root location block, otherwise it cannot even override the settings of the other location block.